# Why does this not work? No matter what IDE I use, this fails

Tags: string, python-2.7

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  result = ""
  for i in text: 
    while i not in "aeiouAEIOU":
      result += i
  return result

print anti_vowel("Hello")
```

This code removes vowels in a string
The ide just returns an empty string or keeps running without printing anything out.

Comment: Use `if i not in` vs `while i not in`

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
while i not in "aeiouAEIOU":
```

will run forever if `i` is not a vowel, which happens in the case of `Hello`. Replace it with

```
if i not in "aeiouAEIOU":
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while i not in "aeiouAEIOU":
  result += i
```

Your loop condition only depends on the value of `i`, but your loop body doesn't change `i`. Therefore, if the loop is entered at all, it will loop forever.

You probably meant to write `if i not in "aeiouAEIOU"`.